# How to get and set CSS class in TinyMCE editor?

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

This is two questions, but one problem:

- how can I get the current/selected object CSS `class`?
- how can I set the current/selected object CSS `class`?

I'm using TinyMCE 3.5.8 (jQuery version).

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate on what you're asking for here.

Comment: hmm... I'm new for TinyMCE programming, but I want to do an `alert()` with the selected object's CSS class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the selected node using

```
var node = tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection.getNode();
```

and the class with

```
$(node).attr("class");
```